# How do I quote a song from Youtube? MLA format

Tags: mla, quotes

I need to quote a song from Youtube. I don't own the song and the artist who sings it hasn't put an official version on YT.

How should I do this? It needs to be in MLA form.

This is the song: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCl01AkVnMo

Comment: When you say "quote", I assume you mean quote lyrics from the performance?  It seems like that would be the same as quoting from any other recording; I wonder what precedents exist for radio, TV, published recordings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can cite it just as you would any other online video:

> Author. "Title of Web Page." Title of the Site. Editor. Date and/or
>   Version Number. Name of Sponsoring Institution. Date of Access `<URL>`.

Or, you may choose to cite it as a film or video recording and put the emphasis on the performer:

> Last, First Name, their participation. Title. Dir. First Last name.
>             Distributor, year of distribution. Medium.

Or, better yet, ask your instructor for guidance on how they would like that particular citation formatted.